# main.js:28 - Type error Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I basically have the following piece of code:

```
if(window.google)
return window.mapInit();
    $.getScript( 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=mapInit' );

//* Google map callback
window.mapInit = function() {


    if (!typeof(google ==='object'))
        return false; // error: google maps API not loaded


    var pos = gmap.pos.split(',');  
    console.log(pos);
    var args = {
        zoom                        : 13,
        center                      : new google.maps.LatLng(pos[0],pos[1]),
        panControl                  : true,
        zoomControl                 : true,
        scaleControl                : true,
        mapTypeId                   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel                 : false,
        draggable                   : true
    }

    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    gmap.map    = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'gmap' ), args );

}
```

The code works fine the first time  - however, if I click on a link to open another map with some new coords, it throughs an error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a[ib]') referring to main.js line 28

does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the file you have posted is main.js? If not, which line is executing while you get the error?

Comment: your script as it is works fine for me, what exactly will be executed when you click the link?

Answer (score 0):

Its because that element is already occupied...maybe...if u want multiple maps on a page...you create a new div everytime. Hope this code helps..

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.id = 'gmapNew';
gmap.map    = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'gmapNew' ), args );
```